# How to return custom error in GraphQL

Tags: php, laravel, graphql

How can I return a custom error from within the `resolve` function of my Laravel project when using GraphQL?

```
public function resolve($root, $args, $context, ResolveInfo $info)
{
    $objDefaultPage = FunnelTypeDefaultPage::where('id', $args['id'])->first();

    if (!$objDefaultPage) {
        return null; // Here I want to return some message instead of returning null
    }

    $objDefaultPage->update($args);
    return $objDefaultPage;
}
```

Comment: Throw an exception and catch it somewhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using [this](https://github.com/Folkloreatelier/laravel-graphql) package then it is fairly simple. If there is nothing special in the error then just return as:

```
return new Error('Default page not found');
```

Don't forget to include `use GraphQL\Error\Error;`
Or if you want to customise it then you need to create a class `DefaultPageError` which should extend the `GraphQL\Error\Error` class and call that class instead. like:

```
return new DefaultPageError('Page not found');
```

Or you can play around more to customise it.